# Непонятный результат при чтении числа с консоли

Tags: java

Подаю на вход число `19`, получаю в консоли `49`. Почему?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int N = reader.read();
        System.out.println(N);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод read() читает один символ char. В вашем случае этот символ - '1'. Символ '1' кастуется в int как 49.
Если вы будет вводить 23, или 2865, все равно будет читаться только первый символ '2' и вы получите int 50.
Печатные символы ASCII (код символа 32-127) [здесь](https://istarik.ru/blog/programmirovanie/53.html)

Comment: Спасибо. Починил `int N = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());`

Answer (score 4):

Используйте `readLine()`, а потом преобразуйте к строке с помощью `Integer.parseInt`. `read()` читает лишь первый символ в Unicode.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int N = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        System.out.println(N);
    }
}
```